# How to load Glide cached image in NotificationCompat.Builder.setLargeIcon()?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-glide, android-notification-bar

[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcM0i.jpg) I am trying to set notification large icon as user profile thumbnail 
like whatsapp or other chatting apps

I have tried

```
 Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(messageNotification.getLargeIcon())
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                   builder.setLargeIcon(resource);

                }
            });
```

but it is not working..
Any Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set the large icon using glide..the you should also notify the NotificationManager `onResourceReady(resource, transition)`

```
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap res, Transition<? super Bitmap> t) {
       builder.setLargeIcon(res);
       yourNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());

    }
});
```

> This is because glide uses **background thread** to load image..so before your image is loaded into builder... the **notification manager is already notified** (mainthread) with builder not having large image..

Comment: SimpleTarget it is deprecated is there any other solution

Comment: @VinitPoojary use CustomTarget<Bitmap>